# MySQL insert Needed data only then send it to crystal report

Tags: java, mysql, crystal-reports, percona

I'm Working on a big project more than 200 table, I'm using MySQL(Percona), Java & Crystal Report JRC.
I have some reports which so big & has a lot of joins between multiple tables.
Inside the Java Client I normally show the data on my frame, in some cases i need to print these data, so i send the unique ID to the Crystal Report to Query the same data and print it.

Some reports become really slow, then an idea came to my mind to create a tables which will be used for printing only.
EXAMPLE:
I have receipt voucher viewed on my Frame if i want to print it, so i insert all needed data on the printing table, then send the unique id to the crystal report and print it.

this printing table will be free up each 48 hours, so the data will be kept small & that make the reports printing faster.

Note: The Original Receipt table will hold millions of records and should be kept for live since this will be a requirement.

but the printing table will be used for printing only.

So, please help me in deciding if this is the best way that i can do to improve crystal report performance with millions of records.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you need to print is already being queried in your java app, then have it create a temp table with only the data i question, and query that temp table in Crystal Reports. e.g.,

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS print_data AS (SELECT * FROM table)`

Otherwise, I would recommend asking this question in https://dba.stackexchange.com/ This is more about database design & performance than Crystal Reports, and if you are experiencing slowdowns in CR when passing a single unique id through an (albeit complex) join structure, then there are either serious performance tuning opportunities, or you have outgrown your hardware &/or MySQL as an adequate solution for your needs.